# Websphere Application Server Liberty 17.0.0.2 - profiles

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

Is it possible to have both profiles on **Liberty 17.0.0.2**.
By both, I mean WAS traditional full profile and Liberty profile on WAS Liberty 17.0.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, no.  The only thing that uses that versioning is Liberty based products and the liberty runtime (profile) itself.  These do not include anything with the full profile / traditional WAS.

In more practical terms, products like "WebSphere Application Server Base" or "WebSphere Application Server ND" 9.0.0.4 includes the 17.0.0.2 liberty profile as well as the 9.0.0.4 "full profile".